# dynamic translation/translation with variable with i18next

Tags: javascript, internationalization, i18next

How come I can't translate dynamically resp. using a variable with i18next?

For example in my JS-file I got this:
Here I use a variable and assign it to the i18n function and it doesn't work:

```
//this does not work:
var dynamicTranslation = "myText.toBetranslated";
console.log("translation dynamic ", !{JSON.stringify(t(dynamicTranslation))});
```

Here I hardcoded the string from above directly into the i18n function and it does work:

```
//inserted string is the same string as in dynamic translation but this does work:           
console.log("translation static ", !{JSON.stringify(t("myText.toBetranslated"))});
```

As a result I get:

> translation dynamic
>   translation static  correct Translation

In order to solve it, I tried to solve it by playing around with setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(function() {console.log("time out translation: " + !{JSON.stringify(t(dynamicTranslation))})}, 2000);
```

But it would still show an empty result:

> time out translation:

Comment: do you happen to have a plunker for it. Cause your syntax seems a bit unfamiliar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's jade syntax. The first code didn't work because it is rendered with jade at the back end site. At that point jade doesn't take the JS part into consideration but only renders it and pushes the result (along with the untouched JS code) to the front end. Therefore the part with the variable inside the t()-function is not translated, because it doesn't take the JS code into consideration.