# What does the notation !{JSON.stringify(t("some.thing"))}; mean?

Tags: javascript, json, internationalization, i18next

I've got a JS code where it says

```
!{JSON.stringify(t("some.thing"))};
```

It is used for translation/internationalization with i18next. But I don't understand the `!{...}` part.

I know what the `JSON.stringify` does. I know what the negation operator `!` means. I don't understand it in combination with the t()-function: When I use it without the `!{...}` part, it says

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: t is not defined
```

But with the `!{...}` part, it translates the part `some.thing` correctly.

`some.thing` is a key in different JSON files for different languages, e.g. a JSON file for english:

```
{
"some": {"thing": "something"}
}
```

and a JSON file for German:

```
{
"some": {"thing": "irgendetwas"}
}
```

Depending on what language is set on your computer, the function `t("some.thing")` will return the corresponding value. If the language of your computer is set to english it will return "something". If it is in German it will return "irgendetwas".

Comment: Is it a minified code? What function is `t`?

Comment: Does this return an object?  t("some.thing");  print this result to the console without all of the other code.

Comment: @AniketSinha the t() is a function from i18next internationalization function.

Comment: @spozun: writing t() without any other code i.e. console.log(t("some.thing)); returns me the error message that t() is not defined. But putting the t() function into the !{...} part makes it defined again.....That's what I don't understand... :(

Comment: And does it return an object?
Use debugger, put a breakpoint on this line and hover over `t` to figure out it's implementation.

Comment: @AniketSinha please see my other comments: No, it doesn't return an object or anything. I get an error message saying that t() is not defined. But putting the t() function into the !{...} part makes it defined again.....That's what I don't understand..

Comment: It might be that it's just been broken for quite a while but the !{} is handling the issue.  Does the whole line return true or false?

Comment: What if you replace {} with JSON.parse?  Does it work?  !JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(t("some.thing")));

Comment: @spozun Nope. It says "Uncaught ReferenceError: t is not defined".

Comment: @spozun the whole neither returns true nor false but translation of the key "some.thing". See my updates.

Comment: What if you update "t" with "i18next.t"....  maybe this will be a little happer:  i18next.t("some.thing");

Comment: @spozun I tried this too but it would return to me an error message: Uncaught ReferenceError: i18next is not defined

Comment: I guess you might just have to show us more code with the i18next.init() call and however else you are wrapping this thing that's hiding the i18next API from whereever this code is.  I have no idea why the api is available sometimes and not other times without seeing more of the surrounding framework code.

Comment: @AniketSinha No, it is not minified code. The function is called t();

Comment: I've been banging my head over this for a while. Post the soln if you find one.

Comment: @spozun I don't know what else to show. The translation-function is very simple. See my other question here about the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40082873/dynamic-translation-translation-with-variable-with-i18next

Comment: @AniketSinha see my own answer. It's Jade syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The curly brackets have nothing to do with objects and the exclamation mark has nothing to do with negation. It's jade syntax for variables used in JavaScript:

http://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/

Answer (score -1):

[**JSON.stringify**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) is a **Javascript** built in function to convert a `JSON` object into a string. The reverse operation would be [**JSON.parse()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

In your code, it seems that `t('some.thing')` is a minified function that returns an Object, that is converted into a `string` and then, checked with a negation operator `!`.

Answer (score -1):

The `!` is `not equal to`.

So technically this would translate to:

> If the output of `JSON.stringify(t("some.thing"))` is `empty` or `null`. Return `true`

More on [JavaScript Comparison and Logical Operators](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

Comment: @thadeuszlay You're welcome. I guess t() is some kind of localizer if you get what I mean.

Comment: Yes, it is a localizer. It's a function from i18next internationalization as I mentioned in my question.